# Update query not updating integer fields using CFQUERYPARAM

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I have a simple update query, only one table involved. I first wrote this without using CFQUERYPARAM and kept getting errors when the integer fields (zip,plus 4, etc) were null. So, I rewrote using CFQUERYPARAM so that the null values didn't produce the errors. Now, when I enter something into the integer fields, the data does not get saved.

What am I missing?

Thanks

DW

```
<cfquery name="updt_person" datasource="#application.datasource#">
  UPDATE tblperson 
  SET 
    firstname = '#form.firstname#', 
    lastname = '#form.lastname#', 
    address_line_1 = '#form.address_line_1#', 
    address_line_2 = '#form.address_line_2#', 
    city = '#form.city#', 
    stateid = #form.stateid#, 
    zip = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.zip#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" null = "yes">, 
    plus4 = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.plus4#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" null = "yes">, 
    area_code = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.area_code#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" null = "yes">, 
    prefix = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.prefix#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" null = "yes">, 
    suffix = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.suffix#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" null = "yes"> 
  WHERE personid = #get_personid.personid#
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first. Please use `cfqueryparam`, to all user inputs when you use it in a query. The fields `#form.firstname#, #form.lastname#, etc` all should be in a `cfqueryparam` to prevent SQL Injection.

The issue you are facing here is the wrong use of `NULL` attribute of the `cfqueryparam` tag.

The `null` param should be an expression which results `true` or `false`. If you provide `yes` as the value directly, then the result becomes like this.

`suffix = NULL`

Now, let us see how to use `null` attribute.

```
<cfqueryparam
  value = "#form.suffix#"
  cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER"
  null = "#len(trim(form.suffix)) EQ 0#"
>
```

The above will make sure `NULL` is passed as the column value if the `form.suffix` is blank. You can change this validation based on your application logic.

Also, newer versions [(CF 11+)](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) does not require the `CF_SQL_` prefix in the `type` attribute.

So the final query should look something like this.

```
<cfquery name="updt_person" datasource="#application.datasource#">
  UPDATE tblperson 
  SET 
    firstname = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.firstname#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    lastname = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.lastname#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    address_line_1 = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.address_line_1#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    address_line_2 = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.address_line_2#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    city = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.city#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    stateid = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.stateid#" cfsqltype = "VARCHAR">, 
    zip = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.zip#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER" null = "#len(trim(form.zip)) EQ 0#">, 
    plus4 = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.plus4#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER" null = "#len(trim(form.plus4)) EQ 0#">, 
    area_code = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.area_code#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER" null = "#len(trim(form.area_code)) EQ 0#">, 
    prefix = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.prefix#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER" null = "#len(trim(form.prefix)) EQ 0#">, 
    suffix = <cfqueryparam value = "#form.suffix#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER" null = "#len(trim(form.suffix)) EQ 0#"> 
  WHERE personid = <cfqueryparam value = "#get_personid.personid#" cfsqltype = "INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: This did the trick. It was me not understanding how the null parameter worked.

Comment: Good answer. (Don't forget to "cfqueryparam" the personID too :-)

Comment: @Ageax I can not believe I missed that. :D